# It is possible to modify unique constraint in sql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm using unique constraint for avoiding duplicates except null values because this column can remains null (it's not mandatory field but it helps in search like search by email e.t.c)

In above situation, Is it is right to choose unique constraint or not?

**Alternative**
As unique allows only one null value, so it is possible to generate different default values for unique constraint? i-e unique for each row.

Comment: If you want to allow duplicates for `NULL` and are using MySQL, then a unique constraint does not do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question both [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), so I'll cover both.

#### SQLite

In SQLite, a UNIQUE constraint will work as you want.

The documentation for [UNIQUE constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#uniqueconst) says:

> For the purposes of UNIQUE constraints, **NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs**.

The documentation for [CREATE INDEX](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) says:

> If the UNIQUE keyword appears between CREATE and INDEX then duplicate index entries are not allowed. Any attempt to insert a duplicate entry will result in an error. For the purposes of unique indices, all **NULL values are considered different from all other NULL values** and are thus unique. This is one of the two possible interpretations of the SQL-92 standard (the language in the standard is ambiguous) and is the interpretation followed by PostgreSQL, MySQL, Firebird, and Oracle. Informix and Microsoft SQL Server follow the other interpretation of the standard.

However, in most other databases, the columns of a UNIQUE constraint cannot be NULL, so I would recommend using a UNIQUE INDEX instead, for consistency, and so as not to confuse people.

#### MySQL

In MySQL, a UNIQUE constraint will work as you want.

The documentation for [Unique Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique) says:

> A `UNIQUE` index **permits multiple `NULL` values** for columns that can contain `NULL`.

A UNIQUE KEY is a synonym for a UNIQUE INDEX.

#### SQL Server

As mentioned in the SQLite documentation, Microsoft SQL Server follow a different interpretation of NULL handling for UNIQUE indexes.

The documentation for [UNIQUE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) says:

> Columns that are used in a unique index should be set to NOT NULL, because **multiple null values are considered duplicates** when a unique index is created.

To work around that, use a filtered index, e.g.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Person_Email
    ON Person ( Email )
    WHERE Email IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: email can be null

Comment: @Coder1 Yes, but the filtered index excludes those, hence allowing multiple records with a null email, since those records are *filtered* out of the index.

Comment: After creating unique index on Email column it says:-------------------------------------------Error while executing SQL query on database 'unique': UNIQUE constraint failed: path.Emial.

Comment: Results according to sqlite.

Comment: INSERT INTO path VALUES ('');

Comment: @Coder1 An empty string is not a NULL string (except in Oracle), so you can only have one record with a empty value. If you want to support multiple empty strings, then you need a filtered index, which is supported by SQLite, but not MySQL.

Comment: The problem still exists thanks for your co-operation @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick with generated columns.  Something like this:

```
alter table t add unique_val as
     ( concat(coalesce(col, ''), ':', (case when col is null then pk end))  ) unique;
```

Where `pk` is the primary key column.

This replaces the `NULL` values with something known to be unique on each row.